# is it good to add 3 index on a table with 30,000 insert in every 15 minutes?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing, partition

I have to make a table with 6-7 partition like this -

Blockquote

```
CREATE TABLE test_cdr 
(  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dataPacketDownLink` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dataPacketUpLink` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dataPlanEndTime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`dataPlanStartTime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`dataVolumeDownLink` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dataVolumeUpLink` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dataplan` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`dataplanType` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
`createdOn` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,  
`deviceName` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,  
`duration` INT(11) NOT NULL,  
`effectiveDuration` INT(11) NOT NULL,  
`hour` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
`eventDate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,  
`msisdn` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
`quarter` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,  
`validDays` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
`dataLeft` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
`completedOn` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,  
`evedate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`evedate`),  
KEY `evedate_index` (`evedate`),    
KEY `hour_index` (`hour`),  
KEY `msisdn_index` (`msisdn`)  ) 
ENGINE=MYISAM 
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(evedate)(  
PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN '2013-9-07'),  
PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-09-10'),  
PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN '2013-09-18'),  
PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-09-23'),  
PARTITION p05 VALUES LESS HAN ('2013-09-25'),  
PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-09-27'),  
PARTITION p07 VALUES ESS THAN ('2013-10-01'),  
PARTITION p08 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

Is it good to make this indexes on this table(with 40+ millions row), because we are going to insert 30,000 records in every 15 minutes. But I also dont want to hurt insert operations? Indexes are too required for fast queries.

So please tell me some intermediate solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: +1, sorry, I misunderstood you question.

Comment: its ok, let me clear this, i have already made this table and we have 20 millions record in it, all i want to know that when i am going to insert records with this rate, m gonna face any problem regarding insertion?